# How can I align my labels and text boxes? CSS

Tags: css

I have the following form: http://imgur.com/pI812gr

With this CSS:

```
#myForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#myForm form {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
#myForm label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px;
}
#myForm input {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#myForm select {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;   //this line does not seem to have any visible effects on the form
}
```

Here is a link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3d44j5to/

How can I align my labels and text boxes in the form as well as put more space between the submit and reset button?

Comment: I like doing forms with bootstrap and it helps me define the alignment and the spacing nicely

Answer (score 0):

use "table" element of html and put your label into one row of "td" and input field in another "td".

like this:

```
<form> 
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Label</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ....
    ....
    </tr>
    ....
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use left alignment

## myForm label {

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: left; //change is here
width: 150px;
```

}